# How can I properly ask this question?

Tags: questions, numbers

I want to ask a question so that I can get the answer which gives the position of the President. So the answer I want to get is:

> Barack Hussein Obama is the **44th** President of the United States.

or

> **44th**.

or simply

> **44**.

How can I properly ask this question?